# Why do we have to revise the definitions of momentum and force in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, forces, momentum, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I get it that we are transforming space and time in a different way, but how does that relate to changing the definitions of force and momentum? I thought that the Gallilean transformations were thought of as a separate thing from Newton's laws. Were Gallilean transformations an assumption of Newton's laws or something?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112471/discussion-on-question-by-ryder-rude-why-do-we-have-to-revise-the-definitions-of).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why do we have to revise the definitions of momentum and force in special relativity?

I am going to downplay the theoretical reasons, because they aren’t what’s important.

What’s important is that the Newtonian definition of momentum is useless because *experimentally* in relativistic particle collisions it isn’t *conserved*. When you change the definition to $\mathbf{p}=\gamma m\mathbf{v}$, this relativistic momentum *is* conserved. So it is a much more useful definition!

It is also then the spatial part of a Lorentz four-vector, which makes it easy to write covariant equations that look the same in all Lorentz frames, but that’s less important. Theories are constructed to explain experiments, and have no *a priori* justification.

Conservation of momentum is more fundamental than what happens when you change reference frames. It holds in all reference frames under both Galilean transformations and Lorentz transformations, as long as momentum is appropriately defined. Conservation of momentum arises from spatial-translation symmetry, and both Newtonian space and Minkowskian spacetime have this symmetry.

Forces (and here I mean three-forces) don’t get redefined in relativity. For example, the Lorentz force is the same whether you are considering non-relativistic or relativistic motion. Newton’s Second Law — which doesn’t *define* force but rather tells you the *effect* of a force — changes so that a three-force now tells you how fast the *relativistic* three- momentum (with the $\gamma$-factor) changes. Why? Most importantly, because this agrees with experiments!

Comment: I disagree with your view on force not being a definition. On the RHS is the force defined in terms of the effect of a source on a particle, on the LHS is a function of the source parameters consistent = the RHS.  First and foremost for Newton IMO, a force causes a particle to change its velocity, when moving in a circle for example, which is why Newton defined force via its effect upon the rate of change of momentum of a particle because of its convenient mathematical simplicity.

Answer (score 6):

Let us propose a 3-vector quantity of the form
$$
{\bf p} = m f(v) {\bf v}
$$
where $\bf v$ is the velocity of a particle, $m$ is an invariant scalar (a property of the particle) and $f(v)$ is some function of speed, to be discovered. Let us then propose that this quantity $\bf p$ is conserved in a two-body collision:
$$
{\bf p}_{A,i} + {\bf p}_{B,i} = {\bf p}_{A,f} + {\bf p}_{B,f}
$$
where $A,B$ refer to two bodies, and $i,f$ stand for "initial, final". It can be shown that, in order that this equation be respected in all inertial frames, the only possible functional form for $f(v)$ is
$$
f(v) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2 / c^2}}
$$

This is not the only way to arrive at relativistic momentum, but it is a conceptually simple way. In the proof one makes use of the Lorentz transformation as it affects velocity.

You can see from this that the quantity defined this way is the only vector quantity depending only on mass and velocity, and having the same direction of velocity, that can possibly satisfy a conservation law without running contrary to the two basic postulates of relativity (principle of relativity and light speed postulate). Those two postulates do not themselves say that momentum is conserved, but they do say that if something momentum-like is conserved, then this is the only possible formula for it.

One can then go on to consider inelastic collisions, and deduce the conservation of $\gamma m$. One then defines energy as $E = \gamma m c^2$. For zero speed this reads $E = m c^2$ and this is one way to derive that famous formula (one defines energy as that scalar quantity related to motion which is conserved in collisions, and one sets the fixed proportionality factor by having the result agree with Newtonian kinetic energy plus a constant in the low-velocity limit).

Answer (score 2):

For starters, your question can be reduced to "why do we need to revise momentum" only, because force can be defined in terms of momentum via

$$\mathbf{F} = \frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt}$$

The reason we are interested in force as a measure of the changes in momentum is because, seen from this perspective, it is *interaction* that is the more basic concept, and one kind of interaction between objects is for them to cause a change in their momenta. Such an interaction can then be quantified by measuring how much the momentum changes, which is what force (and for momentary interactions, impulse) refers to.

So why do we need to re-define momentum? The answer to this is that, for the idea of an altered spacetime geometry to be useful, we must have some sort of "play" that occurs between the spacetime geometry and the dynamics defined on it, so that there is a logical relation between the two and the form of one cannot be changed without impacting that of the other. This means that the different spacetime geometry must cause a different dynamics to prevail, and so momentum, as a dynamical quantity, should be expected, on that dint alone, to have to change. Explaining the reason it changes to *this particular form* takes a bit more work, however.

Comment: Where can I read up on the details about the reason of introducing a $\gamma$ in momentum? So far, Lorentz transforms are the only thing I know about special relativity.

Comment: @RyderRude See Feynman’s argument in section 16.4 [here](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_16.html). Ignore the part about “relativistic mass” and focus on the fact that relativistic *momentum* needs a $\gamma$.

Comment: Can you explain how the Newtonian dynamics is logically connected to Gallilean transforms? I saw them as logically separate rules

Comment: @RyderRude Not here. That question is quite different from your original question and would likely lead to a lengthy discussion unrelated to this answer.

Comment: @G.Smith I've asked a separate question for that now:https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/578080/how-are-galilean-transformations-logically-connected-to-newtonian-mechanics/578085?noredirect=1#comment1303528_578085

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we have to revise the definitions of momentum and force in special relativity?

The definition of force has had many forms, depending on the context. To start with it was to describe how many horses were needed to carry a weight, that is why people still speak of a horse power for a car.

When using mathematics to model observations one has to be clear if one is talking of horses or spacecrafts, i.e. the context . In each theoretical model there are many ways of writing a measurable/observable quantity within the formulae used in the specific model.

The basic mathematical form that exists in all theoretical models, and is correct  in all theoretical contexts, from field theory  and quantum mechanics to cosmological models, is the $F=dp/dt$ which  avoids the separate definition of mass and velocity, since in the relativity frame *mass is not an invariant quantity*, **but** energy and momentum are still conserved absolutely.

Momentum is not redefined, in every theory it is $mv$, except that $m$ is redefined in special relativity,as the "length" of t[he energy/momentum four vector.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) , because   for very high energies it was observed that mass was not an additive conserved quantity, in contrast to the low energy theories.

Comment: I asked about momentum too. Why $\gamma mv$ instead of $mv$? What do Lorentz transforms have to do with this revision?

Comment: I could not disagree more. I consider it pedagogical malpractice to think that Newton’s 2nd Law defines force.

Comment: “Relativistic mass” is today widely recognized as pedagogical malpractice

Comment: @G.Smith  I do not understand your comment. I am saying completely the opposite, the newtons law is appropriate in newtonian mechanics.

Comment: You seem to clearly be saying that $F=dp/dt$ defines force. I disagree. It is not a definition of anything. It is a physical law telling you what the result if a force is.

Comment: And... Relativistic mass has been discussed innumerable times on PSE. The consensus on this site, and among physicists today, is that it is a terrible, outdated, and *pointless* concept that does nothing but confuse students.

Comment: I completely agree with the latter, and will edit to make clear my meaning as I am not defining force by dp/dt

Comment: After an edit, you’re now saying that relativistic momentum is the *invariant* mass times the velocity. That’s incorrect.

Comment: @G.Smith  think again. This is true only for elementary particle whose invariant mass is fixed by the SM table axiomatically. . Otherwise the vectorial sum of four vectors has a "length" which is the mass of the composite system, larger than the mass of the sum of the constituents.

Comment: This discussion could go on for a very long time. Since I’m seeing the “Please avoid extended discussions in comments” message, I won’t continue.

Comment: @G.Smith Mind clarifying "pointless concept" a bit? I'd like to open a Q&A on this

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon It wouldn’t be appropriate to use comments to Anna’s answer to have a discussion with you about relativistic mass. I suggest using this site’s search box to search for “relativistic mass” and reading previous questions and answers. If you then have a further question that hasn’t been answered, post it.