# How are Galilean transformations logically connected to Newtonian mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

I used to think of them as separate independent rules. But after making the [Why do we have to revise the definitions of momentum and force in special relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/576620/) post, I realised that they're not separate.

How are they connected though? Does one imply the other? Why would some velocity transformation other than the Galilean transformations not make sense for Newtonian mechanics?

EDIT- The key equations in Newtonian mechanics are $F=ma$ and $F_{12}=-F_{21}$. And Galilean transformations are $x'=x-vt, t'=t$. Does one of these imply the other? How are they the "perfect" match for each other? Help me see how they are not independent things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Galilean transform is thoroughly baked into Newton's *Principia*, from his definitions, his laws, his corollaries, and his scholia. Newton mentioned Galileo's ship experiments multiple times in his *Principia*. Newton's definition of quantity of motion (what we now call linear momentum) makes it very clear that the Galilean transform is assumed to be true. His first two corollaries essentially state that forces are three-vectors.

The Galilean transform is even more thoroughly baked into modern teaching of Newtonian mechanics. Displacements, velocities, momenta, accelerations, and forces are taught as three-vectors. Most introductory physics texts start with one or more chapters that describe how three-vectors behave, and how one takes derivatives of those three-vectors with respect to time.

That those key quantities can be treated as three-vectors with time as the independent variable implicitly assumes that the Galilean transform is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Newtonian mechanics is valid only in *inertial reference frames* (existence of which is postulated by the Newton's first law), which are the reference frames that are related via the Galilean transformations (in non-relativistic mechanics). I don't really see how one can see Newtonian mechanics and Galilean transformations separately...

**Update**
To expand in a bit more details:

- **Inertial reference frames** are references frame where a body, if acted upon by a zero net force, does not accelerate. Newton's first law is essentially a restatement of this definition: *There exist such reference frames where ...* (I assume that no one here confuses Newton's first law with a particular case of his third law.)
- **Galilean transformations** allow to recalculate the coordinates and momenta from one reference frame to the other.
- **The first postulate of relativity** is that the laws of physics are the same in all inertial frames of reference.
- **Lorentz transformations** transform between different reference frames, accounting for the second postulate of relativity (constancy of the speed of light).

Thus, Galilean transformations can be viewed either as a Newtonian version of the Lorentz transformations (i.e. Lorentz transformations at $v\ll c$) or as a restatement of the first postulate of relativity for Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: You basically just said 'Newtonian mechanics is valid in frames related by Galilean transformations'. This does nothing to answer the question.

Comment: I think the question is incorrectly posed. It  is grounded in misunderstanding of the Newton's first law, which is essentially a restatement of the Galilean principle.

Comment: With the exception that the relative velocity between two inertial frames cannot be equal to or exceed the speed of light in special relativity, inertial frames in Newtonian mechanics and in special relativity are identical.

Comment: And the Galilei group is exactly the group (contraction cf. [Inonu-Wigner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_contraction)) one obtains by taking $c\rightarrow\infty$ in the definition of Pincaré transformations.

Comment: I have always considered the first law as a special case of the second law. I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: @Vadim In the second last line of the post, I do ask 'Does one imply the other?'. So please show how Galilean transformations imply Newton's laws.

Comment: The first law is the same thing in relativity as well. It's the second  law (when stated as F=ma) and third law which are unique about Newtonian mechanics.